# Change PS1 value for all Bash users

Tags: debian, bash, bashrc

I am trying to change the prompt value for all users of a system (the $PS1 variable) to the same value.

I have the following stored in file /etc/ps1:

```
PS1='`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then echo -n "\[\033[00;35m\]\u\[\033[01;32m\]@\[\033[00;35m\]\h\[\033[00;32m\](\[\033[01;35m\]\W\[\033[01;32m\])\[\033[00;32m\]\$";
    else echo -n "\[\033[00;35m\]\u\[\033[01;31m\]@\[\033[00;35m\]\h\[\033[01;31m\](\[\033[35m\]\W\[\033[31m\])\[\033[00;31m\]\$";
  fi`\[\033[0m\]'
```

Under my single user account I can add `source /etc/ps1` to my ~/.profile file it works (interestingly it didn't work when I added that to ~/.bashrc). If I add this to /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc.basrch to make this happen for all users, nothing happens. I'm puling my hair out trying to get this to work. This is on Debian 7.1.0 (Linux 3.2.46).

Comment: Your assignment is inside out. For readability and maintainability, I recommend that you use the form: `if ...; then PS1=...; else PS1=...; fi; PS1="$PS1\[\033[0m\]"` removing the backticks and echoes. I have represented it here on one line due to the limitations of comment formatting, but you should maintain indentation similar to that of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add your modified PS1 setting to `/etc/profile.d/custom_ps1.sh`. Files under `/etc/profile.d` are automatically sourced from `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Which is called whenever a login shell is spawned. From the [`bash` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.